# How to fix the display in DataGriView?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, ado.net, display

when i clicked on Load_Table Button, I want to display table from my database in DataGridView, So i wrote that code :

```
private void Load_Table_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Server=ZIKO_RED2486;Database=Students;Integrated Security=true"))
                {
                    if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                        cn.Close();
                    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Student", cn))
                    {
                        cn.Open();
                        da.Fill(dt);
                        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
```

- When i clicked the first time it display Student table as expected,
  But when clicked the second time The DataGridView display the Student
  table twice.
  which mean :
  [image]
- it looks like the Load_Table button take the data of Student table
  and display it on the content of datagridview.
- i thought of delete the content of datagridview before getting the
  data from the table to display it one time. But it still not working.

Help Please.

Comment: Since you're storing the DataTable, make it new before filling it again. You could also create a DataTable in the same procedure (`var dt = new DataTable; da.Fill(dt); dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;`). If you need to share the data with other Controls, use a BindingSource and store it as a Field.

Answer (score 1):

```
 private void Load_Table_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Server=ZIKO_RED2486;Database=Students;Integrated Security=true"))
            {
                if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    cn.Close();
                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Student", cn))
                {
                    cn.Open();
                    // we clear 
                    dt.Tables.Clear();
                    // then we fill 
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `ds` and `dt` are different things.

Comment: Do dt.Tables.Clear();

Comment: If `dt` is a DataTable, it does not have a `Tables` collection.  Test your code before posting.

Comment: i think he use DataSet :))

Comment: No, it looks like a DataTable.  He never clears the rows, so when the adapter fills it, it keeps adding more rows.

Comment: i just add 

              dt.Tables.Clear();
Before
                    da.Fill(dt);
and it works

Comment: Why do you answer twice the same question

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear `DataGridView1` before refilling it:

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

Comment: Can't do that when the grid is using a DataSource.

Answer (score -1):

just clear your datagrid view

```
this.dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
```

Comment: Can't do that when the grid is using a DataSource.